# "Perfecting" an endomorphism in a category

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, morphism

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a complete category and suppose $f: X \to X$ is an endomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$. Associated to $f$ is an inverse system,
$$X_\bullet: \dots \to X \to X \to X \to X,$$
where every arrow is $f$, and we can form a map of inverse systems $f_\bullet: X_\bullet \to X_\bullet$, again just via $f$. Taking inverse limits, we arrive at $\hat{f}: \hat{X} \to \hat{X}$.

In any concrete category where inverse limits can be represented as [sets of coherent sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Algebraic_objects), it's easy to see that $\hat{f}$ is an epimorphism. Indeed, given a coherent sequence $(x_0, x_1, \dots)$, we have that
$$\hat{f}(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots) = (x_0,x_1,\dots).$$

> Is it always true that $\hat{f}$ is an epi? If not, what counter-examples exist? What kind of conditions could be imposed on $\mathcal{C}$ to ensure $\hat{f}$ is an epi?

It seems like this holds for a large class of categories (e.g. all complete abelian categories, by Freyd–Mitchell), so I'm curious to see just how general it really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you can prove that in the category of sets this $\hat{f}$ is even an isomorphism : indeed, in that category $\hat{X}$ can be represented as the set of coherent sequences you mention, and you have a map
$$\gamma:\hat{X}\to \hat{X}:(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto (x_1,x_2,\dots).$$
You have proved already that $\hat{f}\gamma=id_{\hat{X}}$, and it's easy to see that $\gamma \hat{f}=id_{\hat{X}}$ as well.

Now using this fact, you can prove that in fact $\hat{f}$ must be an isomorphism in any complete category. Indeed, by the Yoneda lemma it is enough to prove that $\hat{f}^* : Hom_\mathcal{C}(\_, \hat{X})\to Hom_\mathcal{C}(\_, \hat{X})$ is a natural isomorphism; but for this it is enough to prove that $\hat{f}^* : Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, \hat{X})\to Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, \hat{X})$ is an isomorphism for all $Z$.

But the universal property of the limit tells you that for all $Z$, $Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, \hat{X})$ must be (naturally isomorphic to) the limit of
$$\dots Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, X)\to Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, X)\to Hom_\mathcal{C}(Z, X)$$
(where every map is $f^*$) in the category of sets, and you can prove that $\hat{f}^*=\widehat{f^*}$ which is thus an isomorphism.

Comment: I presume in your final indented line you should write $X$ not $\hat{X}$ in the homs? But thanks for the enlightening answer.

Comment: Here is a fun example: let $X = S^1$ in the category of compact Hausdorff abelian groups, and let $f : X \to X$ be given by $z \mapsto z^p$. Then $\hat{X}$ is a group called the $p$-adic solenoid; it can be thought of as the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ (which arises via the dual construction of a colimit rather than a limit in abelian groups). The identification of the Pontryagin dual gives some indication of what this process has to do with attempting to invert $f$.

Comment: The map $x \mapsto x^p$ (and the process of "perfecting" an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra it's defined on) was indeed what inspired this question!